# Exclude files in Sonar Code Coverage Analysis Test - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, sonarqube, karma-jasmine

How do I exclude ts.files in SonarQube Analysis for better Code Coverage.

I tried with with below code

```
"test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "codeCoverageExclude": [
              "src/app/user/about-report/about-report.component.ts"
            ],
          }
       }
```

But no luck its is getting analized in sonar. Can you help me out. I am using Angular 7.

Answer (score 7):

In `sonar-project.properties` , Try adding something like:

```
sonar.exclusions= **/*.spec.ts, **/*.ts, src/test/*
```

Comment: can't we do this in project level.

Comment: @Rajesh Yes, you can. create this `properties` file at project level. It takes relative path.

Comment: try with sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/myfolder/**  because the propertie sonar.exclusions not allow to sonar find bugs and other issues in your code in these files that are excluded,  however sonar.coverage.exclusions= only exclude files for  test-coverage

Answer (score 1):

There is the following directive that can be used in the `sonar-project.properties` file:

```
sonar.coverage.exclusions=src/main/webapp
```

Or via website, go to Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope > Code Coverage and set the Coverage Exclusions property